# Rails Migrations. Why does migration not work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.1

Im trying to migrate something i found on the net and
rails db:migrate has no effect. I tried one of the other posts that suggested moifying migration file to report errors, but still no response after trying again.

```
class CreateDoctors < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1] 
def change
  create_table :doctors do |t|
  t.decimal :clinic_latitude, precision: 10, scale: 6
  t.decimal :clinic_longitude, precision: 10, scale: 6
  t.string :clinic_name
  t.timestamps
  end
  add_index :doctors, [:clinic_latitude, :clinic_longitude]
  end
end
```

I generated a new test migration Users. and that migrated fine. Also i dropped db and recreated to no effect.

Comment: so what happens when you run it?  Nothing at all?  Can you pose the exact path to this file you are trying to run, and also the exact command you are using to run it?

Comment: App/models/doctors.rb rails db:migrate I suspect that generating the model might resolve this. But have not tried that. Next step. Tomorrow.

Comment: that is not the right place for a migration file.  It sounds like maybe you are confused by the Rails setup?  Migration files go in the `db/migrate` directory.  It would probably be best to generate the migration via `rails g migration` and add these attributes.  Have you ever done that?  This might help https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

Comment: and delete that file you added wherever you added that into

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can't add some file to migrations folder and hope that it'll be migrated ever.

You need to `rails generate migration create_doctors`, and then paste what you need to **that** migration that was created automatically.

Comment: this answer was already in my comments. no biggie

Answer (score 0):

Starting a migration fixed it as Rusian tersly suggested and as i put in comments that i would try when i got back to the computer today.